# How to resolve React DateTimePicker returning SyntheticBaseEvent value onChange

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks, datetimepicker

I am using the React `DateTimePicker version 3.2.4 ("react-datetime-picker": "3.4.2")` and having a weird issue. I am using it in a form an auto-populating the form with the current date:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker';
import config from '../../config/config';
import axios from 'axios';

function AddMeetingForm() {
  const [meeting_name, setName] = useState('');
  const [meeting_location, setMeetingLocation] = useState('');
  const [date_time, setDateTime] = useState(new Date());

 // A bunch of irrelevant code
  
  const calendarChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setDateTime(new Date(event));
  };

  return (
    <div className='container all-center'>
      <div
        className='card text-center'
        style={{ background: '#54c5f1', width: '385px', height: '700px' }}
      >
        <form onSubmit={mySubmitHandler}>
          <h3 style={{ textDecoration: 'underline' }}>
            Complete the Add Meeting Form and hit submit:
          </h3>
          <div className='grid-container'>
            <div className='grid-item' style={{ width: '350px' }}>
              // Irrelevant inputs

              <label>*Meeting Date/Time</label>
              <DateTimePicker
                required
                type='text'
                name='date_time'
                id='date_time'
                onChange={calendarChangeHandler}
                value={date_time}
                style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', width: '466px' }}
              />
              <label>Notes</label>
              <textarea
                id='notes'
                name='notes'
                onChange={myChangeHandler}
                style={{
                  width: '100%',
                  marginBottom: '10px',
                  resize: 'vertical',
                  maxHeight: '200px',
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button
            className='btn btn-primary'
            type='submit'
            id='addMeetingBtn'
            style={{ marginTop: '40px' }}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default AddMeeting Form
```

Everything works ok if the user uses the dropdown to change the day, month, year, or time. However, if the user want to manually change 1/21/2021 to 2/21/201 by typing '2' into the input box, the debugger shows that, rather than a new Date being based in the change event, something called a `SyntheticBaseEvent` is passed which breaks the code when it tries to plug in an invalid date into the DateTimePicker input:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

An error is then thrown: `Uncaught Error: Invalid date: Invalid Date`. Why is this happening, and how can I catch or prevent this `SyntheticBaseEvent` from occuring?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxpot.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by the event only picking up one part of the formatted date time. To resolve this I made the following changes, which resolves the issue.

```
 <DateTimePicker
       required
       type='text'
       name='date_time'
       id='date_time'
       onChange={(date) => setDateTime(date)}
       selected={date_time}
       value={date_time}
       style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', width: '466px' }}
       format='MM/dd/yyyy h:mm aa'
       showTimeInput
       timeIntervals={40}
       showTimeSelect
 />
```